# Netbeans J2ME SVG Compliance

Tags: netbeans, svg, java-me, standards-compliance

I coded some svg images for a project i'm working on. But when i try to put them on a screen(form) in the netbeans software (j2me), it says "the image is not SVG Tiny compliant". I've even tried testing with svg images from Sun's WTK demo's **THAT WORK** when deployed but it says the same thing. Any ideas on whats gone wrong?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying that the WTK demo SVG files also display the error when launched from netbeans?

Answer (score 2):

Well you have to realize there is a difference between **SVG** and **SVG Tiny**, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVG_Tiny) kinda explains that.